# Ошибка при склонении в родительный падеж pymorphy2

Tags: python, pymorphy2

Использую `pymorphy2` не могу понять как решить проблему. Пытаюсь просклонять в родительный падеж слово, но выдает ошибку

```
import pymorphy2 
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
month = morph.parse(text_Rus)[0]
gent = month.inflect({'gent'})
print(gent)
```

ошибка:

```
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'. Did you mean: 'getargs'?
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Что будет если заменить `getargspec` на `getargs`?

Comment: так в том то и дело что в коде нету таких слов

Comment: https://github.com/pymorphy2/pymorphy2/issues/159 Вы пробовали использовать решение от сюда?

Comment: посмотрел я по вашей ссылке решение, я установил pymorphy3 и вроде как работает выдает Parse(word='декабря', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,gent'), normal_form='декабрь', score=1.0, methods_stack=((DictionaryAnalyzer(), 'декабря', 195, 1),))